# boost interruptible_wait and abandoned winapi mutex

Tags: c++, winapi, boost, boost-thread

How can I interruptible wait on native windows mutex and deal with mutex abandoning? I can't use `boost::this_thread::interruptible_wait` because it simply returns `false` in case of abandoning, and there is no way to distinguish that from the timeout or error, and understand that mutex have to be released.

Why boost `interruptible_wait` doesn't support abandoned mutexes?

For now seems like I solved this problem with my own implementation, but it is using undocumented features:

```
bool InterruptibleWait(HANDLE h, DWORD timeout) {
  // this function differ from boost::thread::interruptible_wait
  // it has additional support of abandoned mutexes (will simply return true)

  HANDLE handles[2] = { };
  handles[0] = h;
  DWORD handle_count = 1;

  auto thread_data = boost::detail::get_current_thread_data();
  if (thread_data && thread_data->interruption_enabled) {
    handles[1] = thread_data->interruption_handle;
    handle_count = 2;
  }

  DWORD result = ::WaitForMultipleObjects(handle_count, handles, false, timeout);
  if (result >= WAIT_ABANDONED_0 && result < WAIT_ABANDONED_0 + handle_count) {
    result -= WAIT_ABANDONED_0;
  }

  if (result == 1 && thread_data) {
    ::ResetEvent(thread_data->interruption_handle);
    throw boost::thread_interrupted();
  }

  return result == 0;
}
```

Is there some proper way?